# IE6 javascript on click image swap problems

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-6

On my webpage I have images that function as checkboxes (image switch and set hidden form property value). It works in every browser except IE6. Does anybody have a clue what is causing this problem?

The code:

```
    function flip(element) { 
      var formElement = document.getElementById(element + "Form");
      var imgElement = document.getElementById(element);
      if (formElement.value == 1) { 
       formElement.value = 0;
       imgElement.src = "images/"+element+".png";
      } else {
       formElement.value = 1;
       imgElement.src = "images/"+element+"2.png";
      }
     }
```

and html example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="inteligencaForm" name="inteligenca" value="0">
<img id="inteligenca" src="images/inteligenca.png" class="pngfix" onClick="flip('inteligenca')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it'll work properly. The error is probably coming from the pngfix you're using.

Comment: it was a combination of pngfix and getElementByID bug.

Answer (score 0):

What does it do?  Nothing?

Try:
`<img id="inteligenca" src="images/inteligenca.png" class="pngfix" onClick="flip('inteligenca'); event.returnValue=false; return false;">`

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, getElementByID is broken on IE <8 and it is confusing the name="inteligenca" in your input with id="inteligenca" in image.

Try removing "name" from the "input"

Comment: I just confirmed this in a test, remove the "name" from input and it works fine in IE6